# Setting tasker to launch a chrome homescreen web app or launch a browser in full screen

Tags: home-screen-shortcuts, chrome-for-android, tasker

Now that Chrome can [create homescreen web apps](https://developers.google.com/chrome/mobile/docs/installtohomescreen) , is there a way to launch these with tasker?

If not, is is possible to set tasker to launch a browser in full screen mode?

Comment: Don't bother trying AutoShortcut or similar apps, I tried and it doesn't work :(

Comment: As a quick update to this, I ended up ...

1. Updating my webapp so that clicking / tapping anywhere on the screen would launch fullscreen mode.
2. Rooting the android stick I was using.
3. Opening up a URL in Chrome using Tasker.
4. Using Tasker to fake a screen tap, which activated my webapp's full screen mode.

Comment: Thanks for sharing! There are some subtle differences between webapp fullscreen mode and what you get from launching a homescreen webapp, but this is an excellent workaround.